# Backbone: adding model from one collection to another

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-events, backbone.js-collections

Here is the general structure I have right now:

Collection 'A' which has view 'A'

to add a model, you can open a modal and choose from a list. The modal is it's own view, 'B', tied to its own collection, 'B'. the view 'B' is instantiated from view 'A' on a click event.

I was going to initialize view 'B' with a 'myParent' attribute so when a model is selected from collection b, I can say this from within view B:

this.myParent.collection.add(newModel).

I know this will work, but is this coupling things too tight that don't need to be? is there a good pattern for this? I was thinking about having several different events and triggers spread about different places but that seems to just complicate things without much added value.

Answer (score 0):

I have come across a similar problem in an application which lists a collection of selectable models in a table. Based on the models which are selected, another view needs to determine which buttons to show to the user.

In this case, I went for an event driven approach. Every time a model from view A is selected, I fire an event which View B listens to and adds that model to Collection B.

For your situation, that could look something like this:

```js
// Your collection view.
var ViewA = Backbone.View.extend({
  
  initialize: function(){
    Backbone.Events.on('modelSelected', this.onModelSelected, this);
    this.listenTo(this.collection, 'add', this.renderList);
  },
                       
  onModelSelected: function(model){
    this.collection.add(model);
  }
  
  renderList: function(){
    // Draw your collection
  }
  
  // Do some clean up of events
  remove: function(){
    Backbone.Events.off('modelSelected', this.onModelSelected, this);
    Backbone.View.prototype.remove.call(this);
  }
  
});
  
  
// Modal View
var ViewB = Backbone.View.extend({
  
  initialize: function(){
    this.collection = new YourCollection();
    this.listenTo(this.collection, 'sync', this.renderCollection);
    this.collection.fetch();
  },
  
  render: function(){
    // Render your modal
    return this;
  },

  renderCollection: function(){
    // Render your collection
  },
    
  // 
  modalSubmit: function(){
    var model = this.getSelectedModel();
    Backbone.Events.trigger('modelSelected', modal);
    this.close();
  }
  
});
```

I should note that this comes with a few caveats. Firstly, I would recommend picking a robust and namespace event naming scheme. This is just an example. Secondly, fetching from the initialize function is often not ideal, but I'm leaving out the concept of controllers for brevity.